# Is the final function specifier redundant when using the final class specifier?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any reason to specify a function as `final` when the class is already `final`? Or is that redundant?

```
class B
{
public:
    virtual void f();
};

class D final : public B
{
public:
    virtual void f() final; // Redundant final?
};
```

Would it be a good rule of thumb to say: Start with making the whole class `final`, and only switch to making individual functions `final` when you need to derive from the class and/or override specific functions?

Comment: if `D` is `final` it cannot be a base class, so I cannot imagine any way to override `f` whether it is declared final or not

Comment: @tobi303, I understand that there is no way to override f(), but are there any other side effects? I checked that the compiler will optimise away the virtual call in both cases (ie final class and final function).

Comment: yeah i am also not sure if there isnt any dark corner in the language where it does make a difference. For example for `std::is_final` i am not sure if a class that is not declared as `final` but has only `final` methods is considered as `final`, however, thats a different question...

Answer (score 5):

It is definitely redundant because marking whole class as `final` makes it impossible to derive from this class and therefore override anything.

> 9 Classes [class]
>
> 3. If a class is marked with the class-virt-specifier final and it appears as a base-type-specifier in a base-clause
>      (Clause 10), the program is ill-formed.

So compiler won't even bother to check whether class deriving from `final` class actually tries to override anything or not.

Answer (score -2):

No, it is not redundant, because `final` means different things when applied to classes and methods.

- When `final` is applied to a class, it means that the class may not appear in the base-specifier-list of another class (i.e. you can't inherit from it)
- When `final` is applied to a member function, it means that the function must be virtual in an ancestor class, and further specifies that it may not be overridden in a descendant class.

The key distinction is that `final` on a member function says that you *must* be overriding a virtual method in an ancestor class- if you're not, the compiler throws an error.  When applied to a member function, `final` is basically an extension of the `override` keyword.

Applying `final` to methods can be very helpful in catching subtle bugs that would not be caught if you only specify `final` on the class.

Example 1: If you have misspelled the function name, or have not perfectly reproduced the parameter list, the function isn't actually overriding the base function and isn't going to be called when you think it's going to be called.  But if you have specified that the function is `final` (or `override`) the compiler will detect that you are not successfully overriding a base function, and will throw an error.  If you have only specified that the class is `final`, the compiler won't care that your function isn't actually overriding a virtual function, and won't throw an error.

Example 2: If you specify that a member function is `final` and the function signature in the base class changes (e.g. someone makes changes to the base class after you've tested and checked in your code), the compiler will helpfully point out that the base function is no longer being overridden by your function.

Comment: As far as I know `final` does not imply `override`. In the example I provided you can change function `B::f()` to `B::f(int)`, or remove the function `f()` from `class B`, or even remove `class B` as a base class from `class D`, and it still compiles.