# May a destructor be final?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, destructor

Does the C++ standard allow a destructor to be declared as `final`? Like this:

```
 class Derived: public Base
 {
      ...
      virtual ~Derived() final;
 }
```

And if so, does that prevent the declaration of a derived class:

```
 class FurtherDerived: public Derived {// allowed?
 }
```

If it *is* allowed, is a compiler likely to issue a warning? Is declaring a destructor to be `final` a workable idiom for indicating that a class is not intended to be used as a base class?

(There is [no point in doing this in a ultimate base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704406/whats-the-point-of-a-final-virtual-function), only a derived class.)

Comment: The idiom for indicating that a class is not intended to be used as a base is to make that class final.

Comment: If you intend to indicate that a class is not suitable to be a inherited from, you can just mark the whole class `final`. `class Devired final : public Base`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> May a C++ destructor be declared as `final`?

Yes.

> And if so, does that prevent declaration of a derived class:

Yes, because the derived class would have to declare a destructor (either explicitly by you or implicitly by the compiler), and that destructor would be overriding a function declared `final`, which is ill-formed.

The rule is [[class.virtual]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#class.virtual-4.sentence-1):

> If a virtual function `f` in some class B is marked with the *virt-specifier* `final` and in a class D derived from B a function `D​::​f` overrides `B​::​f`, the program is ill-formed.

It's the derivation itself that is ill-formed, it doesn't have to be used.

> Is declaring a destructor to be final a workable idiom for indicating that a class is not intended to be used as a base class?

Effectively, but you should just mark the class `final`. It's quite a bit more explicit.

Comment: "...but you should just mark the class `final`". And [doing both would be redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704769/is-the-final-function-specifier-redundant-when-using-the-final-class-specifier).